# Why does WordPress rely on an fully qualified site_url with a 15-step plan for moving a site?

Tags: database, domain, site-url, home-url

From the [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) codex page (emphasis mine):

> When your domain name or URLs change there are additional concerns. The files
>   and database can be moved, however references to the old domain name
>   or location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues
>   with links or theme display.
>
> If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the
>   URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact
>   that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL
>   marked. When this changes, things break. To avoid that serialization
>   issue, you have two options:
>
> 1. Only perform a search and replace on the wp_posts table.
> 2. Use the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) Script to safely change all instances. ( If you are a developer, use this
>      option. It is a one step process as opposed to 
>      the 15-step procedure
>      below )

What are the benefits of saving the site_url vs. using relative links? Is it because of performance? Or is there some other benefit (e.g. SEO-related or technical) when hyperlinks in the content are fully qualified?

Because it certainly makes WordPress more difficult to use when developing in a team, when you have a shared database with your test/acceptance environment, and when 'going live' with a WordPress website.

Comment: We use `define('WP_HOME'` and `define('WP_SITEURL'` during development and testing, but that doesn't solve the serialization issues, and therefor doesn't make the 15-step process or the [3rd-party script](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) obsolete at all.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been discussed several times on the WordPress Hackers email list, I'd recommend Googling something like `wp-hackers absolute relative` to get an overview of the various lively debates that have taken place over the years.

Personally I use the [searchreplacedb2](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script whenever I migrate a database between URLs, e.g. from live to local/test/dev.